# "drush up" turns off all of my modules

Tags: drush

I'm using drush to make version updates and any time a module (in todays case, recaptcha) needs to be updated, it successfully does the update.  However it seems to reset the database turning off every single non-core drupal module.

I cant find anything about this on the internet anywhere. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you run drush up, you are actually updating Drupal core along with contrib modules and themes. Try:
drush up recaptcha -y
This will update the recaptcha module only, with no confirmation needed.